# How to index objects inside array in JSONB field?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13, postgresql-json

I want to `index` the `JSONB` field with `GIN` indexing. Inside this field, I have an `array` of `objects`. Precisely, this is how it looks (shortened second `object` with three dots):

```
[
    {
        "tags": ["student work", "fast apply"],
        "intensity": [
            {
                "shift": "fulltime",
                "period": "hours",
                "duration": "9"
            },
            {
                "shift": "parttime",
                "period": "hours",
                "duration": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    { ... }
]
```

This is how I filter this table in `WHERE` clause:

```
items.intensity @? '$[*] ? (@.tags == "student work" || @.tags == "undefined" || @.tags.size() == 0) ? (@.intensity[*].shift == "fulltime")'
```

This is the index I tried but didn't work:

```
CREATE INDEX idxginintensitytags ON items USING GIN (intensity jsonb_path_ops);
```

Explain analyze:

```
    #   Node    Rows    Loops
Actual
1.  Bitmap Heap Scan on items as items (rows=154922 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: (intensity @? '$[*]?(@."intensity"[*]."shift" == "fulltime")'::jsonpath)
Heap Blocks: exact=33478
154922  1
2.  Bitmap Index Scan using idxginintensitytags (rows=154922 loops=1)
Index Cond: (intensity @? '$[*]?(@."intensity"[*]."shift" == "fulltime")'::jsonpath)
154922  1
```

I want to filter my `table` by `tags`, `shifts`, `periods`, and `durations`. I have 200,000 `rows` in that `table`.

How can I `index` this `field`?

I am using the latest version - `PostgreSQL 13`.

Comment: Your example data doesn't have any keys named "target" so what is your example query supposed to do with all of those targets?

Comment: @jjanes Sorry for that. Edited the query

Comment: If your query really returns 154922, that is not going to be blazingly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my hands, a problem is that it does use the index, even though doing so is slower.  And the reason for that is that `@.tags.size() == 0` cannot be determined by the index, so it ends ups returning all table rows to be rechecked, but the planner evidently doesn't realize this will happen.

Can you express this concept in a different way?

Comment: I can ignore @.tags.size() == 0 if it is a problem for performance

Comment: Removing that definitely speeds things up for me.  If it doesn't work for you, please edit your question to include an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` of the query.

Comment: Added it to my answer. Performance is the same as before, there is no improvement. I shortened the filter but it didn't help either